# dynamically layout buttons .net

Tags: vb.net, button, layout, dynamic

Hie everyone

I have a procedure which puts buttons on a .net windows form using vb.net. It works ok but because I do not know the number of buttons I will be programming because they come from the database I would like a way to lay them out in rows of 10. I have programmed up to 50 which ios 5 rows but the method I am using will not work if there is more than 50. Is there a way do  this. I have tried using mod of the number of boxes and it does not work.

Here is the code.

```
 Private Sub AddButtons()
        Dim xPos As Integer = 0
        Dim yPos As Integer = 0
        Dim n As Integer = 1
        Dim numberOfBoxes As Integer

        numberOfBoxes = txtNumberOfBoxes.Text
        numberOfBoxes = numberOfBoxes + 1
        ' Declare and Initialize one variable
        Dim btnArray(numberOfBoxes) As System.Windows.Forms.Button
        For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfBoxes
            btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Next i
        While (n < numberOfBoxes)
            With (btnArray(n))
                .Tag = n + 1 ' Tag of button
                .Width = 100 ' Width of button
                .Height = 100 ' Height of button
                If (n = 11) Then ' Location of second line of buttons:
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos = 120
                ElseIf (n = 21) Then
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos = 240
                ElseIf (n = 31) Then
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos = 360
                ElseIf (n = 41) Then
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos = 480
                ElseIf (n = 51) Then
                    xPos = 0
                    yPos = 600
                End If

                'If n Mod 10 = 0 Then
                '    xPos = xPos
                '    yPos = yPos + 50

                'End If
                ' Location of button:
                .Left = xPos
                .Top = yPos
                ' Add buttons to a Panel:
                pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnArray(n)) ' Let panel hold the Buttons
                xPos = xPos + .Width ' Left of next button

                .Text = (n)

                ' for Event of click Button
                AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Me.ClickButton
                n += 1
            End With
        End While
        btnAddButton.Enabled = False ' not need now to this button now
        Label1.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `FlowLayoutPanel` or, more likely, a `TableLayoutPanel`.  You configure it to grow in the manner required and then all you have to do in code is `Add` the `Button` to its `Controls` collection.  It handles all the layout so there's no calculation required.

Comment: thanx jmcilihinney. I will have a look at do it that way,

Comment: http://softwaredevelopmentforecm.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/dynamically-generating-a-tablelayoutpanel/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub AddButtons()
    Dim numberOfBoxes As Integer = txtNumberOfBoxes.Text

    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfBoxes - 1
        'since row is an integer it won't have decimal places
        'also \ divides without decimales-
        Dim row As Integer = i \ 10

        'The modulo operator is your friend. it gives you 
        'the rest of the devision.
        '   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation
        Dim col As Integer = i Mod 10

        Dim newButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        With newButton
            .Tag = i + 1 ' Tag of button
            .Width = 100 ' Width of button
            .Height = 100 ' Height of button
            .Left = col * .Width
            .Top = row * (.Height + 20)
            .Text = i + 1

            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Me.ClickButton
        End With
        pnlButtons.Controls.Add(newButton)
    Next i

    btnAddButton.Enabled = False ' not need now to this button now
    Label1.Visible = True
End Sub
```